# AWS Route 53 Email Verification stuck due to (stupidly) using the domain as the registrar contact email

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-route53, verification, icann

As mentioned in the title. I have a domain that I transferred to aws Route 53. I bought the domain during a university hackathon and hastily used the domain in the registrar email.

**(e.g. domain = example.com, registrar email = info@example.com)**

Fast forward to now: it looks like there are a series of email verifications that need to be responded to before the domain will be fully transferred. The problem, as stated before, is that the registrar email is on the suspended domain, thus no emails are going through.

Is this domain lost forever? I've tried contacting the new and old registrar with no avail. Perhaps I need to figure out how to reach out to ICANN at this point.

Comment: Why is the domain "suspended?"

Answer (score 0):

I did this once and found that, if the registrars have approved the transfer, then AWS can provisionally transfer the domain for 14 days, under the condition you set up email and confirm the validation emails in that time frame. If you don't they will revert the domain back.

Open a ticket with AWS and they can walk you through the process.